# Drop certain rows depending a conditional check after performing a group-by function

Tags: python-3.x

I have 2 columns, I want group-by using column A and then check whether three different values exist for that group in Column B; if not then drop the entire row.

[Please check the image for input and output required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84fn4.png)

In the above output, I had to drop ABC since it only has 1 and 2, while I needed it to have 1,2, and 3 at least once

```
ColA    ColB

ABC     1
ABC     2
XYZ     1
PQR     1
PQR     2
XYZ     2
XYZ     3
PQR     3
PQR     2
XYZ     1
ABC     2
```

Output

```
ColA     ColB

XYZ       1
          2
          3

PQR       1
          2
          3
```

I have tried using for but it not working

Comment: Could you show your code? It's totally unclear, why your question is tagged "python", not sql. Also, it's difficult to help you without knowing your approach.

Comment: Hey, I am trying to achieve the above using Python, I guess it can be done using SQL too. The solution provided by Maria below works fine for me, in case you want to understand what I was trying to achieve please refer below Maria's comment. Thanks

Comment: Oh, my bad, sorry for misunderstanding the question, I have not read it attentively enough, saw "columns" and "group by", didn't think about files and Pandas.

Comment: No problem, I hope it is clearer now. I didn't know how to put it well

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [ ('ABC', 1),
         ('ABC', 2),
         ('XYZ', 1),
         ('PQR', 1),
         ('PQR', 2),
         ('XYZ', 2),
         ('XYZ', 3),
         ('PQR', 3),
         ('PQR', 2),
         ('XYZ', 1),
         ('ABC', 2)
    ]
#create set dataframe   
data_df = pd.DataFrame(list(data), columns=['col_a', 'col_b'], )


#pull unique column b values, pull a list of all unique integer values. This will be used to figured out which col A values does not contain all of the values
dfSetB = set(list(data_df['col_b']))

#sort by column a
dfSorted = data_df.sort_values('col_a')

#pull unique values from a, will need this for the loop that will filter the data by col A values
dfColAValues = set(list(data_df['col_a']))

#check all col a values to see if it contains all unique values from col b
inclusion_list = []
#work your way through each unique col A entry
for col_item in dfColAValues:
    #filter the data-set based on col_item value
    dfTemp= data_df.loc[data_df['col_a'] == col_item  ]   
    #pull list of unique col B values for that specific col A entry
    dfSetTemp = set(list(dfTemp['col_b'])) 
    #check and see if the list of unique col B values for the entire data-set matches all of the unique col B values for that specific col A entry and if it does, append it to the inclusion list
    if dfSetTemp == dfSetB:
        inclusion_list.append(col_item)

#filter data to only include col a values that contain all unique values from col b and drop duplicates        
dfFinal= data_df.loc[data_df['col_a'].isin(inclusion_list)].drop_duplicates(subset=None, keep='first', inplace=False).sort_values(['col_a', 'col_b'])
```

output:

```
  col_a  col_b
3   PQR      1
4   PQR      2
7   PQR      3
2   XYZ      1
5   XYZ      2
6   XYZ      3
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly fine. Can you please explain why you created a set of unique values, I am fairly new to Python

Comment: @nehaparekh I updated the code with more comments. Basically, I used a set for col A to filter the data-frame, and from here I used the set of unique col B values to see if this filtered data-frame also contains all of the unique numbers that came from the master data-frame.

Comment: Also can you please explain the following line of code .  <dfTemp= data.loc[data['Campaign'] == col_item]>

Comment: @nehaparekh that's used to filter the data-frame based on that specific column value. If col_item = "PQR", then the resulting data-frame will only include PQR entries.

Comment: Got it, I know my questions might sound silly but am new to coding. Thanks a ton, this helps a lot